# searching for a short story with a theme park full of robotic fair folk powered by uploaded personalities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, fairy, mind-uploading

A  short scifi story in an anthology of short scifi stories - Setting is  an entirely automated amusement park with a sort of Land Of Faerie  theme. All park character robots are controlled by AIs made partially  from uploaded human consciousnesses but only the protagonist, the leader  of the Wild Hunt really understands this and remembers fragments of  their human life. The park was abandoned a long time ago and apparently  the civilization which built it deteriorated enough that centuries later  when humans moved in, nobody interrupted either to stop the trespassing  or protect the squatters from rampaging haywire robo-fair folk. A pack  of vicious mechanical hellhounds the size of bears were involved. The  story also had a "dog toy" consisting of a transparent plastic ball with  a holographic projector displaying the moving illusion of a sort of  tiny winged fairy inside it which the protagonist used to destroy the park's controlling computer by tossing it at it and having a bear-sized robotic dog stomp through the delicate vacuum tubes to 'fetch'. It was written in English and based off the presence of a vacuum-tubing based computer treated as a serious plot point, probably quite old.